# How to authenticate REST API with Go client and Oauth1?

Tags: go

Trying to consume REST API which uses Oauth1 with GO client.
With Posmant I'm using this configurations and it works fine:
[auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geOqQ.png)
and
[advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbYLK.png)

My Go code look like this:

```
config := oauth1.Config{
    ConsumerKey:    "key",
    ConsumerSecret: "secret",
    Realm:          "realName",
    Signer:         new(oauth1.HMAC256Signer),
}

token := oauth1.NewToken("token", "tokenSecret")

httpClient := config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)

resp, _ := httpClient.Get(URL)
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Printf("Raw Response Body:\n%v\n", string(body))
```

What configuration is missing in my code? Getting 401 error.